# Previous version files not visible in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, vss, previous-versions

We have about 50 computers which are connected in network.But in some Windows 7 pc i cannot see previous version files for some folders which are in network. Previous version files for that folder is visible in Windows xp but only in windows 7 it shows blank.Any idea about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that that you haven't turned-on System Protection in: Control Panel -> System (System Protection in in the LEFT menu).

[image]

Comment: My problem is that a folder in a network path is having previous version set on it. but in windows 7 if i goto that network path and goto its properties and then previous version tab i can't see any previous version files list. If i do the same in windows xp for the same network folder i can see list of files in previous version tab.